# Splitting line and adding numbers to a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have several text files in a folder, all with data in the form of numbers, each separated by 3 spaces. There are no line breaks. I want to take the numbers, put them in order in a numpy array, and then reshape it to be a 240 by 240 array. (I have the correct number of data points in each file to do so.) Afterwards, I want it to display my array graphically, and then do the same for the next file. However, my attempts keep giving my errors that say:

```
"'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 10-11: malformed \N character escape."
```

My code so far is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = np.array([])
import glob, os
os.chdir("/mydirectory")
for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    for line in file:
        numbers = line.split('   ')
        for number in numbers:
            a.np.append([number])
    b = a.reshape(240,240)
    plt.imshow(b)
    a = np.array([])
```

Comment: have you looked at numpy.loadtxt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like a number with reading one of the files.  I'd suggest first doing a

```
 lines = file.readlines()
```

and making sure that the lines look right.  You may also want to add a `strip`

```
In [244]: [int(x) for x in '121  342  123\n'.strip().split('  ')]
Out[244]: [121, 342, 123]
```

But this looping structure is also bad.  It's a misuse of `np.append`

```
a = np.array([])
....
for number in numbers:
    a.np.append([number])

In [245]: a=np.array([])
In [246]: a.np.append(['123'])
...
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'np'

In [247]: a.append(['123'])
...
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'

In [248]: np.append(a,['123'])
Out[248]: 
array(['123'], 
      dtype='<U32')
In [249]: a
Out[249]: array([], dtype=float64)
```

`np.append` returns a new array; it does not change `a` inplace.

You want to collect values in list (or lists of lists), or at the very least pass a list of integers to `np.array`:

```
In [250]: np.array([int(x) for x in '121  342  123\n'.strip().split('  ')])
Out[250]: array([121, 342, 123])
```

Comment: Thanks. This was very useful